# Is it possible to use JSCover or any other tool to get JavaScript code coverage running Java Selenium WebDriver tests in Browser?

Tags: javascript, java, selenium-webdriver, code-coverage, jscoverage

Is there a way to run Selenium WebDriver tests in a browser (or just run a test scenario manually in a browser), and get the code coverage of the web-app written in JavaScript? Are there any other code coverage tools except JSCover that can do such task?

Answer (score 1):

> Is there a way to run Selenium WebDriver tests in a browser (or just
>   run a test scenario manually in a browser), and get the code coverage
>   of the web-app written in JavaScript?

JSCover can when run in [proxy mode](http://tntim96.github.io/JSCover/manual/manual.xml#gettingStartedProxy) (without HTTPS). A more robust approach would be to pre-instrument your JS before running your tests, which can be done by JSCOver and other tools (see answer to second question).

[JSCover can also save data between pages using local-storage](http://tntim96.github.io/JSCover/manual/manual.xml#localStorage) which can be useful for re-using existing selenium suites.

You'll need to add some code to the end of your tests to save the coverage data. To do that with JSCover, see http://tntim96.github.io/JSCover/manual/manual.xml#fileSystemSave.

> Are there any other code coverage tools except JSCover that can do
>   such task?

There is also [Istanbul](http://gotwarlost.github.io/istanbul/) and [BlanketJS](http://blanketjs.org/) which may be able to be used with the pre-instrumentation approach.